# Reuse just specific property of another class in scss

Tags: sass, extend

it is possible to reuse all properties of another class in scss using the @extend method.

```
.class1 {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
}

.class2 {
   @extend .class1;
   border-color: #000000;
}
```

Which will result in

```
.class1, .class2 {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
}

.class2 {
   border-color: #000000;
}
```

Is it possible, to reuse *only custom properties* of another class? Something like

```
.class2 {
   @extend .class1.height;
   border-color: #000000;
}
```

Which results in something like this

```
.class1 {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
}

.class2 {
   height: 10px;
   border-color: #000000;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can, but for that you need to extend a [placeholder](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors) rather than a class. you abstract the desired properties to a placeholder, and apply at desired classes:

```
%custom-height {
   height: 10px;
}

.class1 {
   @extend %custom-height;
   width: 10px;
}

.class2 {
   @extend %custom-height;
   border-color: #000000;
}
```

which will result in:

```
.class1, .class2 {
   height: 10px;
}

.class1 {
   width: 10px;
}

.class2 {
   border-color: #000000;
}
```